# Mysql InnoDb cluster adding new instance causes exception

Tags: virtual-machines, centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mysql-cluster

I have created `Centos 7` VM instance on Google cloud. I installed `MySql 8.0` on this. Configured all proper settings. Edited `my.cnf`. After finalizing my instance I created the snapshot of this instance and created two more instances from this snapshot.

I have to configure the `Mysql InnoDB` cluster using `MySQL` shell. Now the issue is there all newly created instance has the same `UUID` as their master node. When I try to add the new instance in `InnoDB` cluster it shows me the following error. I am literally stuck here. please anyone guide me how can I change the UUID of newly created machines. So that new noded can be added in `MySQL Cluster`.

Following is the error for

```
cluster1.addInstance('root@*******:3306', { memberSslMode: 'REQUIRED', ipWhitelist:'**********************'}); 

    Cluster.addInstance: Cannot add an instance with the same server UUID (1ddc0de3-8050-11e8-8cc0-42010a8e0003) of an active member of the cluster 'server2:3306'. Please change the server UUID of the instance to add, all members must have a unique server UUID. (RuntimeError)

[root@server3 server3]# ls -ltr /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jul  5 13:19 51a7c7e4-4490-4c13-a7aa-446d8606cef5 -> ../../sda1

[root@server2 ~]# ls -ltr /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jul  5 12:19 51a7c7e4-4490-4c13-a7aa-446d8606cef5 -> ../../sda1
```

Answer (score 1):

The server UUID is stored in the file `auto.cnf`. Your snapshot should not contain this file, so that MySQL in each created instance generates its own unique UUID. Delete it and create a new snapshot.